# Можно ли автоматически изменять название строки в getString()?

Tags: java, строки, kotlin, textview, android-resources

Суть в том, чтобы автоматически изменять строку, подставляемую в TextView, напрмер:

1. Есть строки с названиями формата : common_q(ЦИФРА ВОПРОСА)

```
 <string name="common_q1">В каком случае водитель совершит вынужденную остановку?</string>
 <string name="common_q2">Сколько полос для движения имеет данная дорога?</string>
 <string name="common_q3">Выезжая с грунтовой дороги на перекресток, Вы попадаете:</string>
```

2. Есть функция, которая ставит текст в TextView

```
fun nextquestion(){
        bindingClass.tvQuestion.setText(R.string.common_qNumber)
    }
```

3. Есть переменная Number, которая изначально =1 и прибавляет +1 каждое нажатие кнопки. Суть в том, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку в TextView записывалась каждый раз новая String путем изменения цифры в конце названия. Можно ли это как либо реализовать в Android Studio с помощью Kotlin ? Ответы для Java тоже будут полезны. Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ресурсах:

```
<string-array name="common_q">
        <item>В каком случае водитель совершит вынужденную остановку?</item>
        <item>Сколько полос для движения имеет данная дорога?</item>
        <item>Выезжая с грунтовой дороги на перекресток, Вы попадаете:</item>
</string-array>
```

В коде:

```
fun nextQuestion() {
    val questions = activity.resources.getStringArray(R.array.common_q)
    var nextIndex: Int = //любым способом определяете номер (нумерация с нуля), например nextIndex = Number - 1
    bindingClass.tvQuestion.setText(questions[nextIndex]) //еще надо проверку на то, что номер валидный, то есть от 0 до 2, но это уже детали
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть вот такой трюк, применим к любым ресурсам.

```
var num = 1
val resId = resources.getIdentifier("common_q$num", "string", packageName)
val finalResId = if (resId == 0) R.string.unknown else resId
```

`getIdentifier()` вернет ноль когда ресурс не найден, значение по умолчанию очень желательно чтобы не поймать позже `NotFoundException`