# Каким бы образом вы это реализовали?

Tags: java, строки, kotlin, textview, jvm

1. Имеем 4 **TextView**, множество **String**, записанных  в формате :

```
    <string name="common_q1"> Вопрос 1 </string>
    <string name="common_a1_1"> Ответ 1 </string>
    <string name="common_a1_2"> Ответ 2 </string>   -- ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ 
    <string name="common_a1_3"> Ответ 3 </string>

    <string name="common_q1"> Вопрос 2 </string>
    <string name="common_a1_1"> Ответ 1 </string> -- ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ 
    <string name="common_a1_2"> Ответ 2 </string>   
    <string name="common_a1_3"> Ответ 3 </string>

    <string name="common_q1"> Вопрос 2 </string>
    <string name="common_a1_1"> Ответ 1 </string> 
    <string name="common_a1_2"> Ответ 2 </string>   -- ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ 
    <string name="common_a1_3"> Ответ 3 </string>
```

Также имеется функция, которая находит ID строк и при нажатии на кнопку записывает в  **TextView**  каждый  раз новую строку ( [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1340763/Можно-ли-автоматически-изменять-название-строки-в-getstring](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1340763/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-getstring)) Т.Е. в **TextView 1** выведется *Вопрос 1*, в **TextView 2** выведется *Ответ 1*, в **TextView 3** выведется *Ответ 2* и тд. При нажатии на кнопку в эти же **TextView** выводится уже новые вопросы и ответы.

2. Суть в том, чтобы в конкретный момент времени знать в каком именно **TextView** хранится правильный ответ на вопрос и организовать проверку на правильность ответа при нажатии на этот **TextView**.

Код желательно для Kotlin, но и Java тоже будет очень полезен

Всем, кто отвечает - огромное СПАСИБО!

Comment: Простейшее для объяснения решение - завести для каждого вопроса еще одну строку, хранящую значение правильного ответа (для первого вопроса это <string name="common_a_correct">@string/common_a1_2</string>). Когда пользователь выбирает TextView - взять текст оттуда, взять текст из соответствующего ресурса правильного ответа и сравнить. Если совпадает - ответ правильный. Отмечу, что это далеко не лучшее решение, но любое нормальное решение сложнее объяснить, а работать вполне будет и так))

Comment: Самое простое решение в лоб: помечать правильные ответы любым не встречающимся в них символом (@,#,$ и т.п.), который перед выводом в UI вырезать.

Comment: По хорошему это реализуется несколько иначе - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345. Также настоятельно рекомендую прочитать книгу в конце ответа, там есть правильное решение такой задачи без БД, хотя взрослые дяди решают первым способом. В настоящее время есть более удобные инструменты, вроде Room, но принцип тот же. Ваше решение изначально пошло не по тому пути и такой подход имеет множество скрытых и явных проблем, я бы не стал развивать в этом направлении

Answer (score 2):

Я бы решил подобным образом:

```kotlin
/**
* @param [question] - это наш R.string.X
*/
data class Question(
   val question: Int,
   val answers: List<Answer>
)

sealed interface Answer {
   val answer: Int // наш ответ в виде R.string.X

   class RightAnswer(override val answer: Int) : Answer
   class WrongAnswer(override val answer: Int) : Answer
}

fun setQuestion(Question question) {
   questionTextView.setText(question)
   recyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter(
      question.answers, 
      callback = { if(question is RightAnswer) pass() else failed() }
   )) // но, лучше, конечно, обновить данные
}

fun pass() {
  // геним тут новый вопрос
}

fun failed() {
  // показываем юзеру что он не прав
}

class Adapter(private val list: List<Answer>, private val callback: (Answer) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<...> // тут наш адаптер
```

Но, можно не запариваться (но это плохой вариант) и просто менять для каждого TextView OnClickListener после ответа:

```kotlin
textView1.setOnClickListener { v ->
   success()
}

textView2.setOnClickListener { v ->
   failed()
}

textView3.setOnClickListener { v ->
   failed()
}
```

Так же, вам стоит понять, что UI должен быть максимально "глупым" и вы не должны делать выкрутасы, как показано во втором примере.

UPD: заполнить `Question` можно следующим образом:

```kotlin
fun questionOf(questionId: Int, rightAnswerId: Int): Question? {
   val question: Int = getQuestion(questionId) ?: return null
   val answers: List<Int> = getAnswers(questionId).mapIndexed { id, answer ->
      if(rightAnswerId != id) Answer.WrongAnswer(answer) else Answer.RightAnswer(answer)
   }
   return Question(question, answers)
}

private fun getAnwers(questionId: Int): List<Int> {
   var x = 0
   val list = mutableListOf<Int>()
   while(true) {
      resources.getIdentifier("common_q${questionId}_a$x", "string").takeIf { it != 0 }?.let { list += it } ?: break
   }
   return list
}

private fun getQuestion(id: Int): Int? {
   return resources.getIdentifier("common_q$id", "string").takeIf { it != 0 }
}
```

Всё что нужно вам - это хранить текущий идентификатор, т.е просто инкременировать какую-то переменную после ответа.

Ещё один UPD: вы делаете всё очень криво, советую вообще отказаться от такого вида вопросов/ответа.

Comment: И собственно ответ на вопрос автора отсутствует. Как заполнить `question.answers` строками из ресурсов, что он привел?

Comment: обновил ответ с ответом на первый вопрос

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja вопрос звучит, как "как бы вы это реализовали?", автор ответа предложил свой вариант решения и я согласен в том, что подход в вопросе стоит вообще забыть и не пытаться что то придумывать и костылить в этом направлении

Comment: @pavlofff, эволюция (и разработчика) должна проходить от простого к сложному. Без понимания как работают базовые компоненты не вижу смысла сразу бежать и делать как "взрослые дяди" делают. Разработчик должен быть готов ко "взрослому решению", взглянув на него воскликнуть: это то что я искал! А не схватиться за голову и уйти в курьеры :)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja есть и простое правильное решение, оно подробно описано у Б. Харди. То, что придумал автор вопроса - это изначально неправильно все, продолжая пытаться заставить это работать, он ничему нужному не научится. Я же как бы не настаиваю, что делай так и все, но развиваться нужно в правильном направлении, я и показал, как правильно